# How can I output blanks instead of "12:00AM" when applying an Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula, where R4 and S4 are times:

```
=TEXT(R4,"h:mm AM/PM - ")&TEXT(S4,"h:mm AM/PM")
```

However, R4 and S4 are sometimes blank, which outputs  `12:00AM - 12:00AM` instead of blank cells.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the formula in an IF statement and test if either R4 or S4 return zero. When true return an empty string.

```
=if(or(R4=0,S4=0),"",TEXT(R4,"h:mm AM/PM - ")&TEXT(S4,"h:mm AM/PM"))
```